# Pros and cons of using mysql_pconnect in php

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-pconnect

I want to know that when I should use mysql_pconnect instead of mysql_connect.

Comment: `mysql_*` is old deprecated extension. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/pdo) instead.

Comment: I know that's an Interview Question, Tell the interviewer that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated.

Comment: I'm not a PHP developer, but reading the documentation seems explanatory. `mysql_pconnect` create persistent (or pooled) connections to the sql server so is not needed to open a new connection to the server each request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is you shouldn't use either because the mysql_* extension is deprecated.

If we rewind several years, then the answer is still pretty much the same - in other DBMS' establishing connections is often slower so persistent connections can be used to increase performance. It's quite common that persistent connections cause more harm than good with mysql/php